# How to round off the totalcost (double) to nearest inetegrs

Tags: c++

I have tried to search similar questions all over the net but non was useful for me.
The nearest I got to was "If the number before the .5 is odd round up, if even round down 13.5 turns into 14 but 12.5 turns into 12".

Coming to the question:

I simply need to calculate the total amount after a meal with the formula;

total amount = mealamount+ mealamount*tip% + mealamount *tax%

I came up with this piece of code (rough only)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    double mealCost;
    double total=0;
    double tipp,taxx=0;
    cin>>mealCost;
    int tip;
    cin>>tip;
    tipp=(tip*mealCost)/100;
    int tax;
    cin>>tax;
    taxx=(tax*mealCost)/100;
    total=mealCost+tipp+taxx;
    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but with the set of inputs of 10.75(mealamonut), 17(tip%),5 (tax %).
the value am getting is 12.50 
if I use

```
int totalSum = std::round(total);
```

its getting converted to 12
but my requirement is 13 .
How to acheive that ?

I cannot find any duplicate question to this if exists 
please mention.

Comment: `std..floor()`, `std::ceil()`

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ I cannot do that ,at run time how can i know what val am getting ,this piece of code fails only with the set of vals I have provided else its fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to convert doubles to integers. You have multiple kinds of round. Check them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), which are [`std::round`, `std::lround`, `std::llround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

On the other hand, if what you want to do is not rounding, but elimination of fractions into one direction, then you have [`std::ceil`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) that goes always higher, and [`std::floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor), that always goes lower.

Remember to include `<cmath>`, not `<math.h>`. The latter is for `C`, not `C++`

Comment: ceil and floor were definitely not applicable for me ,but thanks for the solution.
std::lround did the trick for me

Comment: @N.Nihar Happy to have helped. Please mark the question as answered by choosing the green checkbox.

Comment: u mean to accept the answer right ! I cannot find something like green checkbox

Comment: @N.Nihar Yes. That's what I mean. That's weird! Please flag it for a moderator... and explain that you can't find a green checkbox. This might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve your goal by using [std::ceil()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) and [std::floor()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) which is defined under `cmath` header file.

Comment: I cannot do that ,at run time how can i know what value am getting ,this piece of code fails only with the set of vals I have provided else its fine for me

Comment: @N.Nihar : If you do your calculations, properly with precision. You can achieve your goal.  17% of 10.75 is 1.8275 and 5% of 10.75 is 0.5375, hence total amount become = 13.115. Now if your take the floor(13.115), then it will return 13.

Comment: can you point what is wrong in my code ,that is what am looking for 

total=mealCost+tipp+taxx;  the output can be anything ,mine code is only failing at a particular test case ,that is with the set I have mentioned so in general I cannot go for a ceil or floor

Comment: @N.Nihar : Change the data type of `tip` and `tax` from `int` to `double` and it will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to always round up so you would need to use the ceil() function. Ceil is short for ceiling and there is also a floor function. Ceiling is up, floor is down, here is a c snippet to try out.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* ceil */

int main ()
{
  printf ( "ceil of 2.3 is %.1f\n", ceil(2.3) );
  printf ( "ceil of 3.8 is %.1f\n", ceil(3.8) );
  printf ( "ceil of -2.3 is %.1f\n", ceil(-2.3) );
  printf ( "ceil of -3.8 is %.1f\n", ceil(-3.8) );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**for rounding to nearest integer math.h has nearbyint**

```
 printf ( "nearbyint (2.3) = %.1f\n", nearbyint(2.3) );
 printf ( "nearbyint (3.8) = %.1f\n", nearbyint(3.8) );
```

Output:

```
nearbyint (2.3) = 2.0
nearbyint (3.8) = 4.0
```

Or if you want to break the default rounding behavior when .5

```
int totalSum= (total - floor(total) ) >= 0.5 ? ceil(total) : floor(total);
```

Comment: ceil an d floor I cannot use as my output is decided on run time . 
coming to  to nearbyint(2.5) produces 2 as output
I need that to be 3 
mine problem is on currency ,so as per the requirement 12.5 must be converted to 13 not 12.

Comment: I added something that may be helpful. round according to the difference between the number and the floor() version of it and then decide to go with floor() or ceil() dynamicly according to the result

Answer (score 0):

1) 10.75 + 17*10.75/100 + 5*10.75/100 = 13.115  ... how comes I can't get 12.50?

2) How do you know it's 12.50, how do you check value of result? (it may be only 12.4999..., so when it is formatted to two decimal places, it will become 12.50) Make sure you do check the actual real value (ideally in debugger or dump memory content in bytes and reconstruct the value by hand), not some string formatted intermediate.

3) this is not some production code, right? Amounts are not calculated with doubles in real financial software, as doubles are not accurate enough and you would run into all kind of hard problems with rounding to VAT, etc. If this is some real thing, you are not up to the task, ask for help some professional.

Answer:

`std::round` should normally do what you need. If it's ending as 12, then it's because the value is less than 12.5.

If rounded to two decimal places it shows as 12.50, you are hitting one of those "all kind of hard problems" of real financial software.

Then you should create your own `round` using string representation, like this example (not handling negative numbers and reinventing wheel probably):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/**
 * Rounds floating point value in std::string type.
 * Works only for positive values, and without "+" sign!
 * ie. regexp ~\d*\.?\d*~ formatting.
 * For malformed input the output is undefined (but should not crash).
 **/
std::string financialRound(const std::string & amount) {
    const size_t dotPos = amount.find_first_of('.');
    if (std::string::npos == dotPos) return amount; // no decimals found
    // copy whole part into temporary result
    std::string result = (0 < dotPos) ? amount.substr(0, dotPos) : "0";
    const size_t firstDecimalPos = dotPos + 1;
    // see if there is 5 to 9 digit after dot
    if (amount.size() <= firstDecimalPos) return result; // no char
    const char firstDecimal = amount.at(firstDecimalPos);
    if (firstDecimal < '5' || '9' < firstDecimal) return result; //not 5-9
    // add 1 to the result
    int patchPos = (int)result.size();
    while (0 <= --patchPos) {
        ++result.at(patchPos);
        if ('9'+1 == result.at(patchPos)) result.at(patchPos) = '0';
        else break;
    }
    // check if additional 1 is required (add overflow)
    if (-1 == patchPos) result.insert(result.begin(), '1');
    return result;
}

void tryValue(const std::string & amount) {
    printf("\"%s\" is rounded to \"%s\"\n", amount.c_str(), financialRound(amount).c_str());
}

int main()
{
    printf("Trying normal values...\n");
    tryValue("12.50");
    tryValue("12.49");
    tryValue(".49");
    tryValue(".50");
    tryValue("9.49");
    tryValue("9.50");
    printf("Missing decimals...\n");
    tryValue("12");
    tryValue("12.");
    printf("Malformed...\n");
    tryValue("");
    tryValue("a.4");
    tryValue("a.5");
    tryValue("12..");
}
```

[live demo](http://cpp.sh/9ayqu) on cpp.sh

Comment: @N.Nihar: I was answering somewhat similar thing in codereview, but I described there more common solutions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140851/110284